# Doctrine: How do i add elements to a relationship

Tags: php, doctrine

i think my question is not clear but i try to illustrate my point here. assuming i have a many to many, self referencing relationship where a user can be a teacher (say u post answers at SO) and a teacher can be a student (u may answer questions but may ask too) too.

```
namespace Entities;
/** @Entity @Table(name="users")) */
class User {
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length="30")
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="teachers")
     * @JoinTable(name="Teachers_Students",
     *              joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="teacher", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *              inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="student", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *              )
     */
    private $students;
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="students")
     */
    private $teachers;

    function getName() {
      return $this->name;
    }
    function setName($name) {
      $this->name = $name;
    }
    function getStudents() {
      return $this->students;
    }
    function getTeachers() {
      return $this->teachers;
    }
}
```

say i have a few users

```
$user1 = new User;
$user1->setName("user 1");
$user2 = new User;
$user2->setName("user 2");
$user3 = new User;
$user3->setName("user 3");
$user4 = new User;
$user3->setName("user 4");
```

and i like to setup teacher-student relationships between them, i was reading up [doctrine reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/working-with-objects/en#association-management-methods), saw that u can use the `Collections::add()` to add elements to a collection

```
// user1 is a teacher to user2 & 3
$user1->getStudents()->add($user2);
$user1->getStudents()->add($user3);

// user2 is a teacher to user3
$user2->getStudents()->add($user3);

// user4 is a student to user2 
// tests if adding something from the inverse side works
$user4->getTeachers()->add($user2);
```

but this fails with

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   add() on a non-object in
>   D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\tools\sandbox\index.php
>   on line 70

how can i add elements to a collection or a relationship?

Answer (score 7):

Remember that your collection variables are just regular ol' class properties. Which means they'll be null until you initialize them. The typical thing to do is instantiate them using Doctrine's `ArrayCollection` class, which will allow you to use the methods you described.

Try this:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->students = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
   $this->teachers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

}
```

Comment: thanks, that fixes it. but must i do that for all relationships? the sample code in the docs don't specify that i must initialize a relationship like this. it only said to use the `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`, etc. annotations

Comment: Above link is broken, however, just spend a few hours trying to figure out why sometimes this properties are correctly initialized and sometimes they are not.